# Sitecore 6.6 and MVC areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sitecore, sitecore6

I am working on a large Sitecore 6.6 MVC site. To be honest, i'm having trouble finding any good information on Google.

My question here is. I am in the Sitecore content editor on a controller rendering.
I want this controller rendering to point to an MVC AREA in my MVC project.

In the data section of my controller rendering in Sitecore I have 2 text boxes:
**Controller**
and
**Controller Action**

What do I type in the Controller text box to point to my area.

My area is this: `<site root>/Areas/UserManagement/ProfileController.cs`

I have tried everything. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Controller field you'd put `Profile` to specify your `ProfileController` and in the Controller Action field you'd enter the name of the Action of the ProfileController that you wish to invoke.

Your UserManagement area will presumably have a `UserManagementAreaRegistration` class where the area specific routes are defined and this will be called from the ApplicationStart event handler.

That's how to wire up controller renderings. When looking at this there are a few stumbling blocks:

1. Action name uniqueness. I haven't managed to get the namespace overload of MapRoute to allow for action names that occur elsewhere in the solution.

   `public System.Web.Routing.Route MapRoute(string name, string url, object defaults, string[] namespaces)`
2. Yet to be able to get the view resolution process to respect area paths, instead it appears to search the standard view folders determined by controller name. From your example I had to drop a copy of my razor view into `~/Views/UserManagement/` to get it to render.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, Yep, I have everything set up with my AreaRegistration. I was having terrible trouble getting anything to work for an area. I am not at work now but I think I got it to work but now it is not rendering my _Layout.cshtml. Ill have a look tomorrow and respond with where I got up to.

Comment: Thanks for this again Kevin, I will try your solution but moving the view out of the area just to make it work does not feel right!

Comment: As a workaround you can reference your view explicity, for example 
`return View("~/Areas/AreaTwo/Views/SimpleArea/Index.cshtml");`

Comment: RuSs, I've documented the workaround in a [blog post](http://kevinobee.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/mvc-areas-in-sitecore/) on Sitecore and MVC Areas.

Comment: Thanks again Kevin. Would it be great, though, if we didn't have to do the following:

View("~/Areas/AreaTwo/Views/SimpleArea/Index.cshtml");

Good solution for now though.